# How to post username and password using Grails RestBuilder

Tags: grails

I am trying to do the same as the following using RestBuilder

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8" --data "</xml_goes_here>" http://www.example.com/api/  -u username:password
```

I have tried the following:

```
def rest = new RestBuilder()
        def url = 'http://www.example.com/api/?username=username&password=password'
        def resp = rest.post(url) {
            contentType("text/xml")
            body(xmlMessage)
        }

def rest = new RestBuilder()
        def url = 'http://username:password@www.example.com/api/'
        def resp = rest.post(url) {
            contentType("text/xml")
            body(xmlMessage)
        }

def rest = new RestBuilder()
        def url = 'http://www.example.com/api/'
        def resp = rest.post(url) {
            contentType("text/xml")
            setProperty("username","username")
            setProperty("password","password")
            body(xmlMessage)
        }
```

Has anyone managed this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with:

```
def resp = new RestBuilder().post(url) {
  auth username, password
  // the rest
}
```